# App Engine return more than 20 full text search results

Tags: google-app-engine, cursor, gae-search

I need to loop through the maximum amount of full text search results with Python App Engine SDK. My code is currently as follows:

```
search_index = search.Index(name="fullText")
indexed_results = search_index.search(search_query) 
for scored_document in indexed_results:
    hits_from_full_text_search.append(scored_document.doc_id)
```

I can see the [cursor class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/cursorclass) should be employed, though I'm not sure how to adjust my above query to continuously loop while a cursor exists.

#### EDIT:

Based on my current data size, I don't expect to need to loop more than a few times, so it should stay within GAE process timeout limits.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18637761/1668057) helped me to come up with the following solution:

```
cursor = search.Cursor()                                          
search_index = search.Index(name="fullText")                      

while cursor != None:                                             

    options = search.QueryOptions(limit=5, cursor=cursor)         
    indexed_results = search_index.search(                        
    search.Query(query_string=search_query, options=options)) 
    cursor=indexed_results.cursor                                 

    for scored_document in indexed_results:                       
        hits_from_full_text_search.append(scored_document.doc_id)
```